# using .Contains() with linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following query that receives a list of ints as a parameter:

```
public int GetMostRecent(List<int> TheIDs)
{
 ...using MyDC...

   var TheMostRecentID = (from d in MyDC.Data
                           where TheIDs.Contains(d.ID)
                           orderby d.DateTime
                           select d.ID).LastOrDefault(); 
}
```

Is this the best way to match a list within a parameter collection to data in the database or is there a better way than using the .Contains() method in linq-to-sql.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you looking for a better way? What do you think is bad about what you're doing now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have is correct. This will be translated into an `IN` clause in SQL with the values supplied in the collection.

On an unrelated note, you should try ordering the query by date *descending* and use `FirstOrDefault()`. As it is now, you're going to bring back the entire result set and throw away every row but one.

Comment: LastOrDefault will even throw an error that this linq is not able to translate it into sql.

Answer (score 4):

You should be careful with such queries with `list.Contains()` inside of `linq query`. Because for each list element it will create a **param** in `sql statement`.

And there's a limited number of params allowed in sql statement, `<= 2100`.
So if your **TheIDs** will contains more than `2100` elements it will **fail**.

If you want to use in this way, you should at least check your **TheIDs** `count` and if more then `2100` dived it in pieces with less then `2100` elements.

Answer (score 1):

This will translate into efficient SQL, so there's no need to use anything else.