# Entity Framework Core where clause with multiple values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table Person with few fields is it. I would like to find multiple people from the DB in one call without putting lots of 'OR's. When I tried the following query I got this error.

```
var list = new List<string>(){"John", "Adam", "Bill", "David"};
context.People.Where(p=>list.Any(l=>l == p.Name)).ToList();
```

error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(p => __list_0
> .Any(l => l == p.Name))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to
> client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
> AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

I guess my query cannot be translated, but is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quick but not usefull answer would be "using an expression that could be translated". Joke aside, IIRC `list.Contains(p.Name)` should work.

Comment: contains will be translated into `WHERE Name IN ('John', 'Adam', ...)`

Comment: I think, there is one problem that when you are writing the query, the link query is always translated to an ordinary SQL query. So you cannot use this statement `list.Any(l=>l == p.Name)`.

Comment: @Musulmon Yeah, that is the problem in fact, OP is asking what other expression would work. In this case it would be `.Where(p=>list.Contains(p.Name))` and internally it would be translated to a `IN (values)` SQL clause

Comment: you need to be aware of a size limitation of your list here. [2100 Items maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29027778/5174469)

Comment: what is the version of the core framework here? There is a [funny trap with contains in 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690473/entity-framework-3-0-contains-cannot-be-translated-in-sql-as-it-was-in-ef-core-2)

Comment: @MongZhu I am using the latest version. EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite 3.1.5

Comment: then contains should work for you, But I am not sure whether it might be evaluated on the client side. Meaning you get the entire table into memory first and then the Contains-filter will be applied. again => not sure

Comment: @bradbury9 your solution worked. I couldn't use contains before, because in actual code my list wasn't just string. I made another string list from it and used contains instead of Any. That took care of it. Thanks!

Comment: can you log the sql statement that goes out to the server? just for my personal curiosity.. :) does it contain the `IN (values)` part ?

Comment: @MongZhu Sorry for the late response. In this case Query is not evaluated in the client side. And yes the generated query contains IN (value1, value2, ...). Good observation!

Comment: great, happy to hear. and thank you for the effort of logging and telling me :)

Comment: @Dilshod ok, glad to help, answer added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is using a function that can be translated into SQL,

```cs
var list = new List<string>(){"John", "Adam", "Bill", "David"};
var matchingPeople = context.People.Where(p=>list.Contains(p.Name)).ToList();
```

The `List<string>.Contains()` is translated into a SQL  `IN (values)` sentence.

**Note**: As @MongZhu points out, in Entity Framework Core 3.0 [there is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58690829/2265446) in that translation and `IEnumerable.Contains()` must be used instead. That bug was solved in 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you try replacing `.Any()` for `.Contains()`? Something like this:

```
var list = new List<string>(){"John", "Adam", "Bill", "David"};
context.People.Where(p => list.Contains(p.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't see an `Any` clause in your answer.